# How to read unicode codepoints greater than 0xFFFF from file in Java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing a lexical analyzer for a compiler and I was wondering how I can read a UTF-8 file that contains unicode codepoints greater than 0xFFFF. The `char` data type only supports two bytes, so how can I read an `int` codepoint from the file?

Comment: In a String, such codepoints are represented by two chars (with values from the surrogate range).  I would naively suppose that reading UTF-8 bytes and then converting to a String would do the right thing.

Comment: You do not have to deal with code points nor `char` to read a text file.  Java can read UTF-8 files into strings. Study up on [Java NIO.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29). Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This has been [covered many many times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+read+UTF-8+file) already.

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is legacy, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead, use code point integer numbers when working with individual characters. Look for code point methods on classes such as String, StringBuilder, Character, etc.

Comment: @BasilBourque: but codepoints are not so useful: there are combining characters, variant selectors, composited forms, etc. The best thing it is to treat strings are black boxes, and using libraries (which known all oddities and exceptions of Unicode [there are a lot]) for specific tasks (splitting strings at good locations, sorting, counting words, space used on screen, etc.)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi To what libraries do you refer?

Comment: @BasilBourque I like ICU. Though I mainly use the C and C++ versions, not java.

Comment: @BasilBourque: ICU (and derivatives) is strictly connected with Unicode. Harfbuzz, Uniscribe or CoreText (depending on operating system) for the metrics, etc. Often there are other specialized libraries (which may use the above libraries, or just code only a specific part of Unicode). But it depends on the tasks. Just we should not write again "the C language book" and so all string functions (good to understand strings and pointer in C, but not so useful as general string functions, but the `char` tend us to go back on such book thinking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently; here's the code I used. It's a `Spliterator.OfInt` implementation that can be used to create an `IntStream` of codepoints from input from a `Reader`, or used directly if that's easier. Or just extract the logic from the `nextCP` method.

```java
package org.raevnos.util.iterator;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;

/**
 * A {@code Spliterator.OfInt} used to iterate over codepoints read from a file.
 */
public class CPSpliterator
    implements Spliterator.OfInt, Closeable {
    private final Reader input;

    /**
     * Create a new spliterator.
     * @param input The {@code Reader} to get codepoints from.
     */
    public CPSpliterator(Reader input) {
        this.input = Objects.requireNonNull(input);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the next codepoint from the underlying stream, accounting for
     * surrogate pairs.
     * @return a codepoint, or -1 on end of file.
     * @throws UncheckedIOException on input errors.
     */
    private int nextCP() {
        try {
            int first_char = input.read();
            if (first_char == -1) {
                return -1;
            } else if (Character.isHighSurrogate((char)first_char)) {
                int second_char = input.read();
                if (second_char == -1
                    || !Character.isLowSurrogate((char)second_char)) {
                    // Hopefully shouldn't happen; caught by Reader first.
                    throw new CharacterCodingException();
                } else {
                    return Character.toCodePoint((char)first_char, (char)second_char);
                }
            } else {
                return first_char;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() { return ORDERED | NONNULL; }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() { return Long.MAX_VALUE; }

    @Override
    public void forEachRemaining(IntConsumer f) {
        int cp;
        while ((cp = nextCP()) != -1) {
            f.accept(cp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer f) {
        int cp = nextCP();
        if (cp != -1) {
            f.accept(cp);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator.OfInt trySplit() { return null; }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException { input.close(); }
}
```

Example usage:

```java
try (CPSpliterator sp = new CPSpliterator(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(whereEver)))) {
    IntStream codepoints = StreamSupport.intStream(sp, false);
    // do something with the stream
}
```

or

```java
try (CPSpliterator sp = new CPSpliterator(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(whereEver)))) {
    sp.forEachRemaining(cp -> doSomething(cp));
}
```

etc.

You can also use `Files.readString()` to read an entire file into a string and use `String#codePoints` or other codepoint methods on it, but the above class is more memory efficient if that matters because it only reads a character at a time. Or read a line at a time and convert those to codepoints.